# concatenate two vector from another vector

Tags: c++, string, vector

I have a vector and in every story, I have a vector where are all the string of my story. I need to verify if two stories have the same name and after that concatenate them.

histoire is story 
titre is the title
histoires->at(i)->getPhrase() = v1 
histoires->at(j)->getPhrase() = v2
a try to do something like

V1.insert(V1.end(),V2.begin(),V2.end());

but it does not work. 
some help, please

```
        for(int j= i+1 ; j < histoires->size(); j++){
            if(histoires->at(i)->titre() == histoires->at(j)->titre()){
                cout << "-------------" << histoires->at(i)->titre() << "-------------" << endl;

                vector<Phrase> it = histoires->at(i)->getPhrase();
                for(int z = 0; z < it.size(); z++){
                    cout << it[z].getOriginal() << endl;
                } 
                histoires->at(i)->getPhrase().insert(histoires->at(i)->getPhrase().end(), histoires->at(j)->getPhrase().begin(), histoires->at(j)->getPhrase().end());
                break;
            }
        }
            break;

    }
```

I need to put the vector v2 in v1 and after that delete the second title with the same name and have just a big story

Answer (score 0):

"i need to put the vector v2 in v1 and after that delete the second title with the same name and have just a big story"

One way to do that would be:

```
v1.insert(v1.end(), 
    std::make_move_iterator(v2.begin()),
    std::make_move_iterator(v2.end()));
```

Assuming I understood your question correctly.